# bash how to change name of the file before moving

Tags: bash

I wrote bash script to export logs from my linux machine to S3. What I want is to add the ip address of the instance to them name of .gz file I am moving and I don't know how to do it.
Here is my script that didn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash

#taking out ip address of the instance
ip4=$(/sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)

find /home/user/tst/logs -name '*.gz' -exec bash -c '
for item do
aws s3 cp "${item/ip4}" s3://s3backups/tst/
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
sudo rm $item
fi
done
' bash {} +
```

If I put "$item" instead of "${item/ip4}", it moves the file but I need name changed and added the ip address there.
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean `aws s3 cp "$file" s3://s3tstadmiralbackups3/SailWeb/"$file.$ip4"`?

Comment: if I do it this way, it creates a new folder and doesn't append the ip address at the end.

Comment: When you have logfile `20220616.gz` and ip-address `1.2.3.4`, what do you want in AWS? 
`s3://s3backups/tst/1.2.3.4/20220616.gz` or `s3://s3backups/tst/1.2.3.4_20220616.gz` or `s3://s3backups/tst/20220616_1.2.3.4.gz`or `s3://s3backups/tst/20220616.gz.1.2.3.4` ? Pleas edit your question with what you want.

Comment: @WalterA Any of those options would be ok since I need it to be unique for that instance. Lets say it could be s3://s3backups/tst/1.2.3.4/20220616.gz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only use `-exec` in `find` for simple commands. Whij not use a "normal" loop?
When the folders are already created in S3, you can use

```
#!/bin/bash

#taking out ip address of the instance
ip4=$(/sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)

while IFS= read -r filepath; do
  filename="${filepath##*/}"
  echo "Processing ${filename}"
  aws s3 cp "${filepath}" "s3://s3backups/tst/${ip4}/${filename}"
  if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    sudo rm "${filename}"
  fi
done < <(find /home/user/tst/logs -maxdepth 1 -type f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first upload the files to S3 bucket with `aws s3 cp` and then iterate over the list of files and use the `aws s3 mv` command to rename them

Comment: I want to rename the files before moving them since I have 2 instances and I don;t know which file is from which instance so adding ip address would separate them. Also, since the naming convention is the same, it moves only one file from one instance (the file with the same name from the other instance is not moved.)

Comment: In the first upload, you could move the files to a folder in the bucket and then during the second move (with aws s3 mv) you can list the files present in the directory and move them back to the root of the bucket with the new file name

Comment: can you give me an example?